# Facing "unqualified type in strict mode for: MessageExchangePattern" while trying to integrate Mule with Drools

Tags: java, mule, drools, esb

i am trying to integrate mule with drools, i have mainly followed the tutorial here but i am getting this error :

> - (1,22) unqualified type in strict mode for: MessageExchangePattern
> - (1,30) unqualified type in strict mode for: ONE_WAY '

it seems impossible to find the solution to me, can any one help me? thanks.

this is my .drl file :

```
global org.mule.module.bpm.MessageService mule;
```

import com.hamgam.hit.esb.*;

```
rule "La Vita Ebela"
dialect "mvel"

when
    $x:XMLDTO( inputXML == "inputXML" )
then
    mule.generateMessage("emc",  "KeyValueMatched", null, MessageExchangePattern.ONE_WAY);
end
```

and this is mules flow :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule 
xmlns:bpm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm/3.6/mule-bpm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.6/mule-vm.xsd ">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        host="localhost" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

        <spring:beans>
            <spring:bean id="dto" class="com.hamgam.hit.esb.XMLDTO" scope="singleton" />
            <spring:bean id="dto-convertor" class="com.hamgam.hit.esb.XMLToDTO" scope="singleton" />
            <spring:bean id="rule-convertor" class="com.hamgam.hit.esb.RuleXMLToDRL" scope="singleton" />           
        </spring:beans>

        <bpm:drools />

    <flow name="basic_tutorialFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <vm:endpoint name = "emc" path="drool.msg" />
        <set-variable  variableName="name" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.uri.params']['name']]" />       
        <set-variable variableName="msg" value="#[payload]"/>

        <logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger" message="Current path is flowVars['name']" />

        <expression-component>
            app.registry['dto'] = app.registry['dto-convertor'].convert(flowVars['name']);
        </expression-component> 

        <bpm:rules rulesDefinition="rule.drl" cepMode="true" initialFacts-ref="dto" entryPoint="XMLDTO stream" />

        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.emc == 'KeyValueMatched']">
                <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#['KeyValueMatched! You are with us on 8084. ' + flowVars['name'] + '. Today is ' + server.dateTime.format('dd/MM/yy') + '.' ]" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#['Nothing! You are with us on 8084. ' + flowVars['name'] + '. Today is ' + server.dateTime.format('dd/MM/yy') + '.' ]" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>

    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

```
import org.mule.MessageExchangePattern
```

Otherwise your Drools MVEL script will have no idea what MessageExchangePattern.ONE_WAY is.

Comment: yeap you are right. i add that line and now i am facing another problem with mule this time : org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Cannot process event as "connector.VM.mule.default" is stopped

Comment: Your mule xml is kinda incorrect, you cannot have a  <vm:endpoint name = "emc" path="drool.msg" /> inside a flow. Your Mule context is probably not up.

Comment: Actually i put it inside the flow just before creating this post. It was outside the flow before. But didnt work. I am just trying to return some text from drools to mule.